# Performing t.test on factors

Tags: r, dataframe

I tried to preform a t.test on two group of factor with out the levels.

The data look lies this:

```
group x

0.4749584
0.5873566
0.5803553
0.5958644
0.5745614
0.562469

group y

0.5873566
0.5803553
0.5958644
0.5745614
0.5624696
```

Then I tried to perform a t.test between the groups:

```
x=process_tomas[2,1:5]
y=process_tomas[2,6:11]
z=droplevels.data.frame(x)
u=droplevels.data.frame(y)
# list_u<-as.list(u)
# list_z<-as.list(z)
t.test(z,u)
```

I got:

> Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") :
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
>   2: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

The list I got from the code looks like this:

[list_u](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou6R3.jpg)

It seems that the levels wasn't dropped.

I checked:

```
z[,3]
[1] 0.5706557
Levels: 0.5706557
```

How can I drop the levels and a preforming t.test?

Answer (score 0):

Provided the data you are looking at converting appears as it does in the first chunk with

```
group x
0.4749584
0.5873566
0.5803553
0.5958644
0.5745614
0.562469

group y
0.5873566
0.5803553
0.5958644
0.5745614
0.5624696
```

he best way to get the values from those lists is to pass the factors through character strings and then to numerics as such:

```
 z=as.numeric(as.character((group x))
 u=as.numeric(as.character((group y))
```

From there you can simply run the t-test and it should be fine.